# Function loading with Modernizr Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr, yepnope

I am trying to impliment a simple jQuery scroll to top function on my site. I tested the code with just jquery/script and it works but when I move the code into Modernizr's conditional load it breaks.

I can't see what I need to set up with the conditional loading to start the function.

```
Modernizr.load([
{
    load: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js',
    callback: function() {
        if (!window.jQuery) {
            Modernizr.load('../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
        }
    },
    complete: function(){
        // External link for rel tags
        $('a[rel="external"]').attr('target', '_blank');

        // Scroll to top
        $(function(){
            $(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
                    $('.scroll-top-wrapper').addClass('show');
                } else {
                    $('.scroll-top-wrapper').removeClass('show');
                }
            });

            $('.scroll-top-wrapper').on('click', scrollToTop);
        });

        function scrollToTop() {
            verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
            element = $('body');
            offset = element.offset();
            offsetTop = offset.top;
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: offsetTop}, 500, 'linear');
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: let me know if the code below works. After reading the modernizr documentation I think it should @user2852784

Comment: Sorry @PaulFitzgerald there was no code below?

Comment: I deleted it as I think you said it still didnt work

Comment: Sorry, yeah it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `load` url to:

```
load: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'
```

Currently, it is not able to call the jquery library from the cdn url you provided.

To help you understand how cdn's work try put both these url's into your browser.

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js` will see jquery library

`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js` will show error

Comment: Thanks for this, I made the changes but still having a problem with the function not working. did a check in console and jquery loads ok and my other jquery for the external link triggers